# Dotnet: OpenTelemetry, connect two scopes

Tags: asp.net-core, trace, open-telemetry, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have three services running on .Net with OpenTelemetry tracing enabled. Communication begins from the first service to the second one via `HttpClient`. Second service handle http request and add work item to its own queued background service. This work item makes http request to the third service.

Traces are exported to `Jaeger`.

I checked traceparent header on the second and third services and they are different.

I think this happened because the second service make http request in background in different scope. (new scope created for each work item)
How can I connect such activity to see the entire communication in one trace?

I tried to create new activity inside work item lambda and set parent activity id but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set parent activity id? Did you use the `Activity.SetParentId` method? According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.setparentid?view=net-6.0):

> This method is only intended for use with Activities created from the
> Activity constructor. Activities created by calling `CreateActivity`
> or `StartActivity` already have the parent ID set, and invoking this
> method has no effect.
>
> This method should only be used before starting the `Activity` object.
> This method has no effect if you call it after the `Activity` object
> has started.

Not sure how your code is structured, but I refer to the example in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/3562) and it works, you can check it. [Here](https://github.com/OmniaSalehSaad/ProjectB) is the code.